# Finding the volume of two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Define two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
$$A = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : |x|+ |y| + |z| \leq 1 \} $$
$$B= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \max{ \{ |x|,|y|,|z| \} } \leq 1 \}$$

1. Find vol($B$)-vol($A$)
2. Set up an integral which evaluates to vol($A$)-vol($B$)

Comment: Sorry guys forgot to add what I already have. Basically I think the max function is a cube, and the other function fits inside that cube but I'm really stuck on finding the volume and setting up the integral.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* For the first, your figure is symmetrical over the octants, so you you're looking at eight times the volume of the simplex bounded by $x,y,z\geqslant 0$, $x+y+z=1$. You're correct that the second figure is a cube.

As further help, if I wanted the area of the two dimensional simplex $x,y\geqslant 0, x+y=1$ I would set up $$A=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}dydx$$

Comment: So then $$A=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_0^{1-x-y}dzdydx$$ times 8? Integrating that I got that A=8/6. And then the cube has a volume of 8 and the volume is 8-(8/6)? I apologize for not showing my work on the integral but I'm not quite sure how to format and edit yet.

Comment: Note that you want to compute $8$ times the volume of a tetrahedron. The volume of the tetrahedron is $1/6 A_bh,$ where $A_b$ is the area of the basis (a rectangle triangle) and $h=1.$

Comment: @RickyBobby [see this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz isn't the volume just $8$ times $\frac 16$ then?

Comment: The area of the basis of the triangle is $1/2.$ So the volume of the tetrahedron is $\frac16\frac12=\frac{1}{12}.$ Thus the volume of $A$ is $\frac{8}{12}=\frac13.$

Comment: So why exactly is it 8 times the volume? @ManuelFdzLpz